# Collectors.groupingBy based on nested static class property

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `College` class with nested static classes `Dept`

**College**

```
class College {
private String collegeName;

private Dept dept;

public Dept getDept() {
    return dept;
}

public void setDept(Dept dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
}

public String getCollegeName() {
    return CollegeName;
}

public void setCollegeName(String collegeName) {
    CollegeName = collegeName;
}

public static class Dept {

    private String deptName;

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
        }

    }

 }
```

I have `list` of `College` objects and trying to `groupingBy` based on `deptName i,e (Map<String>, List<College>)`, But no luck so far and it gives a compilation error message

```
List<College> list = new ArrayList<College>();
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(College.Dept::getDeptName));
```

**Compile Error**

```
The method collect(Collector<? super College,A,R>) in the type Stream<College> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<College.Dept,capture#1-of ?,Map<String,List<College.Dept>>>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
College.Dept::getName
```

is a `Function<College.Dept, String>`. It doesn't accept a `College` as an input.

Use a lambda to construct a `Function<College, String>`:

```
groupingBy(c -> c.getDept().getName())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Map<String, List<College>> map = 
         list.stream()
             .collect(groupingBy(college -> college.getDept().getDeptName()));
```

**Update:**

These two observations may be off topic, though I believe they're worth mentioning:

1. Is the identifier of class property `CollegeName` capitalized intentionally? I would highly recommend using the same coding style all over your code.
2. Looks like you need to rethink your data hierarchy (even if it's just a tutorial task). The relation between `College` and `Dept` shouldn't be `one-to-one`, but `one-to-many` instead.